# How to run WebApi?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Hi I am learning WebApi in VS2015. I have some experience in MVC4 so i know concepts of Routing in MVC$. I am following http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/65794e/web-api-with-angular-js/ website. I am trying to display some data from database as below.

```
public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        // GET: api/Test
        public WebAPI db = new WebAPI();
        public IEnumerable<LoginTbl> Get()
        {
            return db.LoginTbls.AsEnumerable();
        }
    }
```

WebApiConfig.cs as below.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{Test}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Service.Js code.

```
app.service("APIService", function ($http) {
    this.getSubs = function () {

        return $http.Get("")
    }
}
);
```

I am not sure what to pass in $http.Get("")
This is my index.cshtml

```
@{

}

<style>
    table, tr, td, th {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 10px;
    }
</style>
<h2>Welcome to Sibeesh Passion's Email List</h2>
<body data-ng-app="APIModule">
    <div id="tblSubs" ng-controller="APIController">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>UserName</th>
                <th>Password</th>

            </tr>
            <tbody data-ng-repeat="sub in subscriber">
                <tr>
                    <td>{{sub.UserName}}</td>
                    <td>{{sub.Password}}</td>

                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

<script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/APIScripts/Module.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/APIScripts/Service.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/APIScripts/Controller.js"></script>
```

I am using AngularJs as clientscript. I am not sure how to run the above application as i can see two RouteConfig.cs and WebAPiconfig.cs. Someone tell me which file i should change in order to run the application? Thank you...

Comment: There are lot of tutorials like : http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/older-versions/creating-a-web-api-that-supports-crud-operations

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am getting required results in the form of XML. I am doing something wrong?

Comment: You need to set that up in your WebApiConfig class.. `config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));`

Comment: `$http.get("<route_here")` basically assumes you're going to pass in a route that has a `[HttpGet]` attribute on it or supports a `GET` request in your API Controller (looking at the tutorial). So in your case in would be `$http.get("api/test")`

Comment: Thanks for your message. Yes i done changes. May i know what would be the url to run? i am using http://localhost:31157/api/test and i will be getting data as [{"ID":1,"UserName":"Hi ","Password":"Bye "}].

Comment: Did you see my second comment?

Comment: Yes. I made changes as you said. I am getting result as [{"ID":1,"UserName":"Hi ","Password":"Bye "}].

Comment: Okay, that's what you wanted, right?

Comment: No i want it in html. I will put my html above. Thanks

Comment: Can you please ask a separate question? Your question in this thread was a) how to get the appropriate route to my controller, and b) how to get the response in JSON and not XML. Your problem now is completely different than your initial question as it is now about rendering data.

Comment: Yes I will raise. Please put answer. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the tutorial you're following, they don't actually say what they named the API controller, but it is called `SubscriberController`. The route matches up with `api/` and then the word before the word `Controller` - so, `api/Subscriber` in the tutorial, and `api/Test` in your case.

In your angular routing configuration, your code would become `$http.get("api/Test");`

In order to return `JSON` from Web API, we'll need this line of code in your WebApiConfig.cs :

`config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am able to get data in Json format.